# How to build this grid with less code?

Tags: list-manipulation, grid-layouts

I have the diagonal and both upper and lower triangulars of a grid.

```
diag = {1, 2, 3, 4};
upper = {{u12, u13, u14}, {u23, u24}, {u34}};
lower = {{l21}, {l31, l32}, {l41, l42, l43}};
```

I want to combine this and display them in a grid with shading.  My code for this is very bulky and I can't help feeling I've missed some function that would make more compact and easier to read. I also would rather not convert everything into `Item` to get the shading I want.

```
diag = Item[#, Background -> LightGray] & /@ diag;
upper = Map[Item[#, Background -> LightBlue] &, upper, {2}];
lower = Map[Item[#, Background -> LightGreen] &, lower, {2}];
first = Append[{diag[[1]]}, upper[[1]]] // Flatten;
mid = Table[Append[{diag[[row]]}] /* Append[upper[[row]]] /* Flatten@
   lower[[row - 1]], {row, 2, 3}];
last = Append[lower[[3]], {diag[[4]]}] // Flatten;
Grid[Partition[{first, mid, last} // Flatten, 4]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is there a more compact way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(*Some pre-format, starting with your element definitions *)
diag = List /@ diag;
upper = Join[upper, {{}}];
lower = Join[{{}}, lower];

(*code *)
f[els_, col_] := Map[Item[#, Background -> col] &, els, {2}]; 
Grid@MapThread[Join, {f[lower, LightBlue], f[diag, LightGray], f[upper, LightRed]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I like the combination method you have used.  Sneaky to add an empty row and and nest the diagonal.

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking I favour using `Grid` options for styling rather than using `Item`. For example make your matrix:

```
MatrixForm[m = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {4, 4}]];
```

then:

```
Grid[m,
 ItemStyle -> {None, None, Flatten@MapIndexed[Which[
       #2[[2]] > #2[[1]], #2 -> Blue,
       #2[[2]] == #2[[1]], #2 -> Gray,
       #2[[2]] < #2[[1]], #2 -> Red
       ] &, m, {2}]}
 ]
```

[image]

Did you start with a matrix and then split it into upper, lower and diagonals? And if you did was that solely for the purpose of styling? If you did then just revert to your starting matrix. If somehow you actually only have the 3 components of the matrix then combine them simply like this:

```
m = RotateLeft@PadLeft[upper, {4, 4}] + 
  RotateRight@PadRight[lower, {4, 4}] + DiagonalMatrix[diag];
```

Or, as per @wreach answer, use negative indexes rather than wrapping to do the rotating:

```
m = PadLeft[upper, {-4, 4}] + PadRight[lower, {-4, 4}] + DiagonalMatrix[diag];
```

Then use the grid styling as before:

```
Grid[m, Background -> {None, None, 
   Flatten@MapIndexed[
     Which[#2[[2]] > #2[[1]], #2 -> Blue, #2[[2]] == #2[[1]], #2 -> 
        Gray, #2[[2]] < #2[[1]], #2 -> Red] &, m, {2}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: You aren't starting from the stated input. Was that on purpose?

Comment: wanted to simply address using `MapIndexed` rather than `Item` for styling of `Grid` but will update

Comment: Ah, using rules. Nice.  I didn't realise the was possible but of course with `MapIndexed`.

Comment: @Edmund  I find it more intuitive doing it that way but it is up to individual preference

Answer (score 4):

A helper function can reduce the boilerplate somewhat:

```
a_ // itemize[c_] := Map[Item[#, Background -> c]&, a, {-1}]

DiagonalMatrix[diag // itemize[LightGray]] +
PadLeft[upper // itemize[LightBlue], {-4,4}] +
PadRight[lower // itemize[LightGreen], {-4,4}] //
Grid
```

[image: grid screenshot]

Comment: +1 nice use of negative indexes to avoid rotating functions

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I abandoned my first solution because your post got there first.  Now I see that my second solution is much like your edit.  Oh well, them's the MSE breaks.  :)

Comment: I like your answer ...although I've never liked using `Item` :)

Comment: This combination is sweet.  I looked at the padding functions but was trying to figure out how to do what you have done with the -4.